# How to use the same function type from another in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/4e9f370f262c171409037dae24fadccb61c35d13/packages/apollo-client/src/core/ObservableQuery.ts#L303

Let's say I want pass `refetch` function as a prop on a component, and this is what I am doing.

```tsx
import { ApolloQueryResult } from "apollo-client"
interface MyQueryVariables{ ... }
interface MyQueryResult{ ... }

interface Props {
  refetch: (
    variables?: MyQueryVariables | undefined
  ) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<MyQueryResult>>
}
```

I have to

1. find refetch function type definition
2. import required types and etcs. e.g. `ApolloQueryResult`
3. write refetch prop as it is in ObservableQuery

, and I am thinking there has to be an easier way.

How would you define the same function type as a prop other than just copy things around like I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof` to get type of some object, including existing function.

For example

```
function refetch(variables?: TVariables): Promise<ApolloQueryResult<TData>>
// Somewhere in code
type refreshFuncType = typeof refetch; // Now refreshFuncType is of type (variables?: TVariables) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<TData>>

interface Props {
    refetch: refreshFuncType
}
```

You have not just `function refresh` but method `refresh` of class `ObservableQuery`. To extract type of method you should use [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) like this

```
type refreshFuncType = ObservableQuery['refetch']; // Now refreshFuncType is of type (variables?: TVariables) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<TData>>
// As ObservableQuery is generic you may provide specific type using ObservableQuery<type1, type2>
```

Not thet no need for `typeof` keyword anymore as indexed access provides type.